# Differentiate two CMAKE pieces. I can't fathom why one does not work

Tags: c++, cmake

What is the difference between:

```
FILE(GLOB CLASSES_FILES RELATIVE ${CLASSES} [^.]*.cc)

FILE(GLOB HANDLERS_FILES RELATIVE ${HANDLERS} [^.]*.c)

ADD_LIBRARY(deti_boot_lib SHARED ${CLASSES_FILES}
                                 ${HANDLERS_FILES})
```

and

```
ADD_LIBRARY(deti_boot_lib SHARED ${CLASSES}/BroadcastSecurityManager.cc
                                 ${CLASSES}/Decoder.cc
                                 ${CLASSES}/Logger.cc
                                 ${CLASSES}/Encoder.cc
                                 ${CLASSES}/Codeword.cc
                                 ${CLASSES}/RandPerm.cc
                                 ${CLASSES}/Symbol.cc
                                 ${CLASSES}/ReceiverSecurityManager.cc
                                 ${HANDLERS}/file_handler.c
                                 ${HANDLERS}/lt_handler.c
                                 ${HANDLERS}/network_handler.c
                                 ${HANDLERS}/time_handler.c)
```

The second works while the first does not. I think i got how file globbing works. This should work!

Comment: Globbing in CMake uses different syntax, than regular expressions. You need something like `FILE(GLOB CLASSES_FILES RELATIVE ${CLASSES} ${CLASSES}/*.cc)` as first command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that did not solve the problem. If i understood correctly ${CLASSES} already defines the working directory.

Comment: Solved it by changing the root folder from ${CLASSES} to ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}

Comment: Obligatory hint that it is dicouraged to use globbing for source files: _We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from
your source tree.  If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is
added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate._ From the [CMake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/file.html).

Comment: @ComicSansMS I was trying to provide with a generic solution for a project that might expect the addition of new files. In a scenario where some of the contributors do not have experience with CMAKE files i found that would fill the need. Is there any good practice for generic solutions like what i am attempting?

Comment: @ComicSansMS Another thing. If i understood correctly. You mean to say that even if i re-run the command (CMAKE) it will not detect new source files?

Comment: If you re-run CMake it will detect the files. The re-run has to be triggered manually though. The recommended way is for users to maintain a list of files in the CMakeLists. That way, when you add a file, you have to edit the CMakeLists, so when you try to recompile it will automatically re-run CMake because the CMakeLists changed. The argument here is that the globbing approach is at best slightly more convenient, but is less flexible and more error-prone. This argument is a bit controversial in the community, but that's the official guideline and I personally tend to agree with it.